# jQuery.parseJSON vs. jQuery.getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm pretty new to using JSON (and to jQuery's Ajax features in general). What I'm trying to do is set up a separate file containing a JSON object, point to that file, store the object as a variable, and access the object's properties using dot notation.

jQuery.parseJSON() sort of allows me to do what I want, but I want to take the next step of pointing to a separate file.

For example, the following behaves exactly as I would expect, opening an alert box that says 'red':

```
var test = $.parseJSON('{"simple":"red"}');
alert(test.simple);
```

The following, which points to a file containing the same JSON object, doesn't work, opening an alert box that says 'undefined':

```
var test = $.getJSON('simple.json');
alert(test.simple);
```

I'm obviously not using this correctly. What's the correct way to do what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: what is simple.json? And you wan't client side javascript to point to a file? Do you mean an object?

Answer (score 7):

Checkout the getJSON docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

you should be doing something like:

```
$.getJSON('simple.json', function(data) {
  alert(data.simple);
});
```

always pays to read the API docs

Comment: That does work, but it doesn't accomplish what I want, which is to have a JavaScript variable that stores the object for later reference.

Based on some of the other solutions offered here, I've also tried both of the following, neither of which work:

`var test;
$.getJSON('simple.json', function(data) {
    test = data;
});

alert(test.simple);`

`var test;
$.getJSON('simple.json', {}, function(data) {
    test = data;
});

alert(test.simple);`

Answer (score 6):

I think you've misunderstood getJSON. It doesn't return a JSON object, but is shorthand for parsing a response text from an AJAX request as JSON.

When you call getJSON, you're actually performing an asynchronous request. When you call alert, the request hasn't come back yet.

Try:

```
var test;
$.getJSON('simple.json', {}, function(data) {
  test = data;
  alert(test.simple);
});
```

Shabba: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 2):

[`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJson/) issues a HTTP GET request to the server and executes a callback when the data is received.

```
$.getJSON('simple.json', function(data) {
    alert(data.simple);
});
```

Alternatively, if you are using jQuery 1.5 or later, you can use the new [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) syntax.

```
$.getJSON('simple.json')
 .success(function(data) {
    alert(data.simple);
 });
```

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Difference between getJson and parseJson

**[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)** is used to load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {  
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {    
        //your actions
});
```

**[jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)** takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript value.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
```

**In other words**

The $.getJSON() method loads the JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request based on a URL to which the request is sent. You may then choose to use $.parseJSON() method to parse the JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure.

Comment: This sentence is confusing me: "You may then choose to use $.parseJSON()...".  Doesn't `.getJSON()` provide data **already parsed** into an object? You would never use `$.parseJSON()` on it, except for some crazy nested JSON-within-JSON situation. Right?

Answer (score 0):

[getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is for loading data, not parsing

> Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

`$.get('path/to/file', 
  function(data) {
    my_variable = data;
  },
  "json"
);`